# best way to form Validation on gae

Tags: python, validation, google-app-engine, forms

(1) is this way : http://code.google.com/intl/en/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html

(2) is write by self :

```
#/usr/bin/env python2.5
#----------------------------
# Datastore models for user & signup
#----------------------------

from base64 import b64encode as b64
from hashlib import md5, sha256
from random import randint
from time import time

from google.appengine.ext import db


N_SALT = 8             # length of the password salt


def salt_n_hash(password, salt=None):
    """
    Generate a salt and return in base64 encoding the hash of the
    password with the salt and the character '$' prepended to it.
    """
    salt = salt or b64( ''.join(chr(randint(0, 0xff)) for _ in range(N_SALT)) )
    return salt + '$' + b64( sha256(salt+password.encode("ascii")).digest() )


class User(db.Model):
    nickname = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    email = db.EmailProperty(required=True)
    pwd = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    suspended = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)

    @classmethod
    def authenticate(klass, nickname, password):
        """Return an User() entity instance if password is correct"""
        user = klass.get_by_key_name(nickname)
        if user:
            n_salt = user.pwd.index('$')
            if user.pwd == salt_n_hash(password, salt=user.pwd[:n_salt]):
                return user

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.nickname == other.nickname


def signup_id(nickname):
    return md5( nickname + repr(time()) ).hexdigest()


class UserSignup(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True)
    date = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

which way is better ,

or did you have better way to do this , ex: a simply form Validation framework,

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Django, `djangoforms` is definitely the way to go.  If [`tipfy`](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/) or other light-weight frameworks, try [wtforms](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/) (it's also in the [tipfy source tree](http://code.google.com/p/tipfy/source/browse/source/lib/wtforms/?r=1055c5164c07761e167a956e32377178d60e3c06)).

Comment: thanks Alex, and did you know is babel easy to use for Internationalization ,  i have a look at it ,and think it is hard ,did you .

Comment: I find tipfy just about as easy to use as webapp.  I have not used the internationalization facilities in either tipfy or django so I can't comment on that.

Comment: i use webapp on gae , so i should choose   djangoforms , not wtforms ,yes  ?

Comment: @zjm, I would recommend djangoforms only if you're using other parts of django as well, otherwise wtforms.